# Change Theme (setTheme) class android Utils "this" error in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, set, themes

Hello i have i Utils class and a fragment class
Fragment class:  `http://pastebin.com/uybNJPpe`

Utils class:`http://pastebin.com/fpSq1wP2`

on "this" in my fragment class i get this error:
**onActivityCreateSetTheme (android.app.activity) in Utils cannot be applied**
Can you help me guys? Please, thank you.
I vote the best!

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Comment: hello i tried but i get this error: **Error:(41, 50) error: as of release 8, 'this' is allowed as the parameter name for the receiver type only, which has to be the first parameter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `this` in your fragment you will get the Fragment instance.

But in your `onActivityCreateSetTheme` method the argument is `Activity`.

So in order to get the `Activity` instance you should pass `getActivity()` in your fragment instead of using `this`.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks. wait 5 minutes, i vote you ;)